# Integration of `connect` on Node.Js failed

Tags: node.js, node.js-connect

Integration of `connect` on Node.Js failed, problem with node `js`. This script cant connect it to `api` . Showing this on browser

> Cannot GET /

here is the tutorial  [click here](https://www.zaincash.iq/portal/en/web/mfs/integration-by-node-js)

```js
var express =  require('express')
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var app  =  express(); 


app.get('/PageAfterClickOnSubmitWithZainCash', function (req, res) {
    jwt.sign({
        amount: 1000,//Product Ammout
        serviceType: 'AAA books website',
        msisdn: 9647911111111,
        orderId: 12345,//optional
        redirectUrl: "http://www.yourwebiste.com/zain_order.php",//optional
    }, 'secretsecretsecretsecretsecretsecretsecretsecretsecretsecretsecretsecretsecret', {
        expiresIn: '4h'
    }, function (err, token) {
        request.post({
            url: 'https://api.zaincash.iq/transaction/init',
            form: {
                token: token,
                merchantId: "572487bca0a4d6f2688c1ee3",
                lang: "ar"//optional
            }
        }, function (err, httpResponse, body) {
            var body = JSON.parse(body); // response of body { id : "asdae123asd123asd" }
            if (body.id)
                return res.redirect('https://api.zaincash.iq/transaction/pay?id=' + body.id);
            return res.redirect('/payment?msg=cannot_generate_token');
        })
    });
});

var connect = require('connect');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static'); 
var app = connect(); 
app.listen(5000);
console.log('working on port 5000');
```

Comment: does it show `working on port 5000` on `node` console

Comment: You overwrite `app` in `var app = connect();` line. So there is no express routes

Comment: @omar did u check?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
this is how to make server in using **Connect**

```
var connect = require('connect');
var http = require('http');
 var app = connect();
 app.use('/test', function fooMiddleware(req, res) {


     res.end('test work')
    });
//test work for me check your api request
http.createServer(app).listen(3000);
```

https://github.com/senchalabs/connect

I run your code on local even its not getting test page with `app.get('/test'..)`.
i am fimilare with express and famous one therefor will suggest **Express.js**

You are mixing express and connect these are two different framework for node.js

> **Connect**: High performance middleware framework. It was authored by TJ
>   Holowaychuk on Dec, 2010.
>   **Express**: Fast, unopinionated, minimalist
>   web framework. It was authored by TJ Holowaychuk on Dec, 2010.
>   [express vs connect](https://npmcompare.com/compare/connect,express)
>   [image: Response for test]

here is my code..actualy your server not getting request.its work for test request hope work for your API request too

```
var express
 =  require('express')
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var app  =  express(); 
app.get('/test',function(req,res){
        res.send('test work properly check your blah API')
        })

app.use('/PageAfterClickOnSubmitWithZainCash', function (req, res) {
    jwt.sign({
        amount: 1000,//Product Ammout
        serviceType: 'AAA books website',
        msisdn: 9647911111111,
        orderId: 12345,//optional
        redirectUrl: "http://www.yourwebiste.com/zain_order.php",//optional
    }, 'secretsecretsecretsecretsecretsecretsecretsecretsecretsecretsecretsecretsecret', {
        expiresIn: '4h'
    }, function (err, token) {
        request.post({
            url: 'https://api.zaincash.iq/transaction/init',
            form: {
                token: token,
                merchantId: "572487bca0a4d6f2688c1ee3",
                lang: "ar"//optional
            }
        }, function (err, httpResponse, body) {
            var body = JSON.parse(body); // response of body { id : "asdae123asd123asd" }
            if (body.id)
                return res.redirect('https://api.zaincash.iq/transaction/pay?id=' + body.id);
            return res.redirect('/payment?msg=cannot_generate_token');
        })
    });
});


app.listen(5000);
console.log('working on port 5000');
```